# Does the suffix L after a number always have the same effect as placing a parenthesis with "long" in it before the number?

Tags: c, type-conversion

Take, for instance, `0xffffffffL`.

Suppose int is 32 bits, is `0xffffffffL` the same as `(long)0xffffffff`? In other words, is the type of `0xffffffffL` long?

Since the type of `0xffffffff` is `unsigned int`, I think that `0xffffffffL` is `unsigned long` rather than `signed long`, though I'm not sure.

Does that depend on whether `long` is 32 or 64 bits?

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from C99 draft standard N1256 (emphasis mine):

> #### 6.4.4.1 Integer constants
>
> [...]
>
> **Description**
>
> An integer constant begins with a digit, but has no period or exponent part. It may have a
>   prefix that specifies its base and ***a suffix that specifies its type***.
>
> [...]
>
> **Semantics**
>
> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.
>
> [...]

```
Suffix             Decimal Constant          Octal or Hexadecimal constant
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
none               int                       int
                   long int                  unsigned int
                   long long int             long int
                                             unsigned long int
                                             long long int
                                             unsigned long long int
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[...]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
l or L             long int                  long int
                   long long int             unsigned long int
                                             long long int
                                             unsigned long long int
```

> [...]
>
> If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list, it may have an
>   extended integer type, if the extended integer type can represent its value. If all of the
>   types in the list for the constant are signed, the extended integer type shall be signed. If
>   all of the types in the list for the constant are unsigned, the extended integer type shall be
>   unsigned. If the list contains both signed and unsigned types, the extended integer type
>   may be signed or unsigned. If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in
>   its list and has no extended integer type, then the integer constant has no type.

Thus, according to the above citation:

- Neither the type or the size of a constant such as `0xffffffffL` is uniquely identified by the suffix. It depends also on the actual bit width of a `long`, which is implementation defined (with a minimum of 32 bit).
- `0xffffffff` is not guaranteed to be `unsigned int`. `unsigned int` has a minimum guaranteed bit width of 16, thus if you are on a platforms where `int`s are 16 bit, `0xffffffff` could well be `unsigned long`. `0xffffffff` can also be an `int` (as pointed out in a comment), i.e. it is not even guaranteed to be unsigned, if `int` type can be used to represent it (e.g. platforms where `int` is 64 bit).
- Adding a parenthesized type in front of an expression is a **type casting** operation, which forces the conversion of the constant to the type indicated in parentheses. Thus the result of the cast `(long)0xffffffff` will have type `long`, but the value depends on a variety of factors, as stated by the standard:

> #### 6.3 Conversions
>
> [...]
>
> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: For completeness, `0xffffffff` could also be `int`, on platforms where `int` has more than 32 bits. Even `long`, but that's not very likely. (BTW, a tip: you can get rid of the bogus syntax highlighting by using `<pre>...</pre>` instead of indenting. Indenting marks the block as code, `<pre>` does not.)

Comment: @hvd thanks for the markup tip! As for the clarification, it can be inferred from the table, but it is worth pointing it out, I'll add it to the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A `L`-suffixed hexadecimal constant will have the first type that could hold that value, out of `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`. It's completely independent of whether the unsuffixed constant would be signed.

In the two situations you're thinking of (32-bit int, either 32-bit or 64-bit long), `0xffffffff` would have type `unsigned` on both systems. `0xffffffffL` would have type `unsigned long` for 32-bit long, and `long` for 64-bit long.

So no, `0xffffffffL` is not the same as `(long)0xffffffff`. The latter always has type `long`, no matter what the range of `long` is. When evaluated, if the value doesn't fit in `long`, you won't get the value you specified. What does happen depends on the implementation. In practice, you probably get -1, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: And what happens with `(long)0xFFFFFFFF` for 32-bit `long`? ID value / "signal raised" as in 6.3.1.3 C99?

Comment: How about UL-suffix? A UL-suffixed hexadecimal constant will have the first type that could hold that value, out of unsigned long, unsigned long long, won't it?

Comment: @xiaokaoy That's correct. Also, if there is any unsigned suffix, it no longer matters whether the constant is decimal, octal or hexadecimal. The rules for `4294967295UL` and `0xFFFFFFFFUL` are the same.